# Delete only inserted rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table in a MySQL database from which I want to select some data and insert into another table. The query is pretty straightforward

**QUERY-1**

```
Insert into ArchiveTable
select * from OriginalTable where ColumnName<utc_timestamp();
```

Now I want to delete the records from **OriginalTable** which were inserted in the **ArchiveTable**

**QUERY-2**

```
delete from OriginalTable 
where ID in(select ID from OriginalTable where ColumnName<utc_timestamp();
```

The problem here is that, while QUERY-1 executes, there would be records which would fullfill the ColumnName
condition but wont be picked up by the query since it has already started executing.
Now on executing the delete statement(QUERY-2), those extra rows would be deleted from **OriginalTable** but I would have no record of them in the **ArchiveTable** since it was not picked up by the previous query.

In SQLServer this can be resolved by using the OUTPUT clause, but I am not sure what would be the best approach to handle this scenario.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated

Comment: The full query did not appear in my original post, here it is Query-1::Insert into ArchiveTable
select * from OriginalTable 
where ColumnName<utc_timestamp();  Query2:: delete from OriginalTable where ID in(select ID from OriginalTable 
where ColumnName<utc_timestamp());

Comment: Group your queries in Transactions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html

Comment: I would add some hash here, md5(pi()*rand()*now()) and use it to store and retrieve inserted rows. Each time you run query you will generate new hash which will expire after you delete records. If I understood this issue correctly.

Comment: There are two ways I can think of: 1. Create an additional column `cleared_from_original` to store a counter suggesting whether the particular row has been cleared from original table or not. its default value will be 0, and will be  updated to 1 at the time of deletion. Second approach could be using a fixed time (instead of utc_timestamp()); let's say midnight of previous day. Let me know if you want me to elaborate this further